# What is the most effecient way to create a list portional to itself?

Tags: python, list, recursion, list-comprehension

I want to make a list such as the next element is based on the value of the previous element. This solution is okay, but i want to know if there is a more efficient way of creating this list.

```
def addelement(stop, x,y):
'''stop is to end the recursion, x is the list, y is the element being appended to x'''
    if stop == 0:
        return x
    x.append(y)
    return addelement(stop-1,x,y-1)

lis = addelement(10, [], 10)
print(lis)
# returns : [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Comment: yes, don't use recursion. It is inefficient compared to iteration, particularly in Python that doesn't provide tail-call optimization. Just use a for-loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is to use Python builtin functions:

```
lis = list(range(10, 0, -1))
```

As it happens, it is also most readable.

If, however, you insist on making your own recursive function, it would probably still be best to not use additional parameters but rather combine the return value with the element being added:

```
def addelement(stop):
    if stop == 0:
        return []
    return [stop] + addelement(stop-1)

print(addelement(10))
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want an recursive approach you can use:

```
def gen_nums(n):
    if n > 0:
        yield n
        yield from gen_nums(n - 1)

list(gen_nums(10))
```

output:

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

but the following  is better(already pointed by @Błotosmętek):

```
list(range(10, 0, -1))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> [*range(10, 0, -1)]
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Some timings:

```
PS C:\Users\...> 1..10 | % { python -m timeit "[*range(10, 0, -1)]" }
500000 loops, best of 5: 457 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 475 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 453 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 485 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 463 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 489 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 481 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 469 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 484 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 455 nsec per loop

PS C:\Users\...> 1..10 | % { python -m timeit "list(range(10, 0, -1))" }
500000 loops, best of 5: 604 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 597 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 578 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 589 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 576 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 572 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 581 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 581 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 595 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 595 nsec per loop

PS C:\Users\...> 1..10 | % { python -m timeit "[i for i in range(10, 0, -1)]" }
200000 loops, best of 5: 909 nsec per loop
200000 loops, best of 5: 923 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 883 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 954 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 910 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 909 nsec per loop
200000 loops, best of 5: 941 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 894 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 882 nsec per loop
500000 loops, best of 5: 911 nsec per loop
```